# Include Vs ProxyCreationEnabled in EF6 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

when we use include method in eager loading for loading the data of the related entities , we get complete data of the related entity and this can be achieved even by enabling proxy creation enabled.

what is the exact difference between creating proxy classes / proxy creation enable and include method used in the eager loading.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Proxies are not used in eager loading. The assignment is done via relationship fixup on the context, because the original query will contain the left outer join and retrieve the entities. However, proxies are required in order for lazy loading to work (additionally, the navigation properties have to be virtual), where they are used as starting points to re-query related data upon access.